# Start Intent activity from fragment fail - android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

I want to start the activity from fragment but fail.

Here is my code

```
MainActivity myactivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();


Intent intent = new Intent(myactivity, PopUpImageActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
myactivity.startMyIntent(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the `intent` from your `activity`, why not doing the `intent` on the `fragment` class itself?

For example,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PopUpImageActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

This should work and there's no need to access your `activity` because all `fragment` resides on an `activity` anyway and it already knows by itself which `activity` it is residing without having it specified

Answer (score 0):

The answer above may/maynot be right but for the best practice always allow transactions through the **Activity** which enclose the *respective* **Fragment**.

Make use of **interfaces**, **onAttach**() in your **Fragment** for giving call to the enclosing **Activity** & from the activity, allow for another activity/fragment transaction.

A sample code would look like this:

```
public class MyFragmentExample extends Fragment{

//Creating instance of Interface
AnyInterfaceName anyInterfaceName;


/*
This onAttach is responsible for attaching the interface
listener of fragment to Activity
*/
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            anyInterfaceName = (AnyInterfaceName) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            throw new ClassCastException(ex.getMessage() + "must implement AnyInterfaceName");
        }
    }

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }


// Define an interface with any name
public interface AnyInterfaceName{
    /*
      you can give any name to this function & this
      function will be implemented later in activity
    */
    void startAnotherActivity();
}
}
```

Now on the Activity side: add this on top just after **extends Activity/AppCompActivity**

> implement MyFragment.AnyInterfaceName

After this, just implement the **method** & inside the method, allow transiting to Another Activity as you do it from Activity using **Intent**.

**Note:**
Don't forget to call to the interface in fragment while you want for starting another Activity. Simply call it like this:

> anyInterfaceName.startAnotherActivity();

It can be a lengthy work to do but for the best practice, it is.

Check out from official android site **Communicating with the Activity** [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Hope it helps !!